# How to trick android and ios devices into thinking they are connected to the internet

Tags: wireless, networking, android

I have an ubuntu machine setup as an access point, but it is not connected to the internet.  I simply want to transfer data between it and smart phones.  The problem is, all devices seem to want to contact their respective servers and verify they can reach the internet, unless settings are changed on the phone.

How can I most easily spoof those addresses?  For instance, Apple serves up a web page that responds with "Success" and a 400.  Google simply sends a blank page with a 204 response header.

Comment: The only way I can see is to write a script that sends the appropriate response headers upon the device connecting. I'll bookmark this question and try to make a solution if I can't find one.

Comment: What kind of data transfer are you looking at? What has access point got to do with it? You could simply hook up the smartphone to the Ubuntu machine with the ubiquitous USB/OTG cable and transfer "files."